# Cannot fetch modified date and time in PDO

Tags: php

Hi I have this code that fetches the date that was set but the thing is it cannot display properly this is where it should display all the investment in the date set

```php
$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales WHERE transtype = 'Investment' && estatus = 'Approved' && approvedate = :now_date");
$stmt3->execute(['now_date'=>$newdate123]);
$total3 = 0;
$totalinvt = 0;
foreach($stmt3 as $srow3) {
    $subtotal3 = $srow3['vAmount'];
    $total3 += $subtotal3;
    $totalinvt = number_format($total3, 2);
}
```

and here is the newdate123

```php
$today = new DateTime(date(), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Taipei'));
$newdate123 = $today->format('Y-m-d');
```

it seems that it is not comparing it properly the output of the approvedate is Y-m-d and also the $newdate123 output is also in Y-m-d format. Thanks!

Comment: $newtoday is **NOT** the same as $newdate123

Comment: sorry let me edit it again wrong variable but it is still not working.

Comment: Using `date()` without any arguments should be producing an error... _"Warning: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: date() expects at least 1 argument, 0 given"_. Remove `date()` and use `new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Taipei"))` instead

Comment: when this new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Taipei")) used, it wasn't accepted by php.

Comment: still wont work.

Comment: Should rather not be using `&&` in your query, but `AND` instead, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and

Comment: _"when this new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Taipei")) used, it wasn't accepted by php."_ - ah, so you got an error message literally saying, "I, PHP, do not accept this" ...? Please learn to be _precise_ in your description of what is actually happening, instead of giving us such overly vague statements.

Comment: When I use the "now" undefined now. Tried setting it to global $now still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you want to get the current datetime in Taipei, please use "now" instead of date() in your DateTime function

Hence, Change

```
$today = new DateTime(date(), new DateTimeZone('Asia/Taipei'));
$newdate123 = $today->format('Y-m-d');
```

to

```
$today = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Asia/Taipei') );
$newdate123 =  $today->format('Y-m-d');

// echo $newdate123 ; will show 2021-10-22
```

For sure the above works, you may see the result here:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9481cf06a2258201bc756cb41b7081596ae7b38

(2) On the other hand, as CBroe has suggested, please rather not be using && in your query, but AND instead. (update your query string please)